# Best way to Overload Methods in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, tdd, overloading

I am using the default Rails tests.

In one test, I am overloading the Date.today method:

```
class Date
  def  self.today
    Date.new(2011,7,19)
  end
end
```

This works great for the tests in this file, but carries over to other tests and causes them to fail. How do I confine the effects of this code to a single file?

I gather that this may not be the best way to do tests. Are there any step by step tutorials that you recommend?

Thanks.

Rails 3.07

Comment: You probably want a mock object. Search for Ruby mock object gems, there are a few to choose from.

Comment: Also, if this is only for Dates and Times, see https://gist.github.com/1033857 (you could try Timecop, but I'll warn you that it has issues with DST that can and will break your tests).

Comment: How would you Mocha to overload the Date object? How do you prevent that override from carrying over to other tests? Where does the code go? Before the test class in the test file? In a test helper file?

Comment: See http://mocha.rubyforge.org/examples/misc.html for examples. `Date.expects(:today).returns(Date.new(2011, 7, 19))`. You shouldn't need to reset anything... it will hook into the unit test framework to reset once the test is finished.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (using `stubs` instead of `expects`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to d11wtq for the code above.

Here's how I did it:

1. $ `gem install 'mocha'`
2. Added `gem 'mocha'` to group :test in Gemfile (see below)
3. $ `bundle install`
4. In model_test.rb file, added `require 'mocha'` on line after `require 'test_helper'`
5. Added the following 3 lines to class ModelTest in model_test.rb:

```
    setup do      
      Date.stubs(:today).returns(Date.new(2011, 7, 19))
    end
```

I found this post a helpful introduction to Mocha: http://yarorb.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/mocks-and-stubs-in-ruby-on-rails-the-mocha-solution/

EDIT: More info:

I discovered that you need to add the following to remove the stub after each test. I put this after the setup method:

```
  teardown do
    Date.unstub(:today)
  end
```

And, I think you need the following gem to the :test group in the Gemfile as well:
  `gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'`

Comment: Thank You B Seven for taking the time to document your final solution.  Fellow SO users will appreciate you taking the time and I'm happy to upvote.